# How to play wav file with 8Kbps bit rate in iOS application?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, bitrate

I develop an iOS application where i should call web service and return audio file ( as byte array ) then play it to user .
I have problem with audio file format as it has 8 Kbps bit rate and no player inside app can play it. when I convert it to any other bit rate for example (13 Kbps) from server side to test it works properly . However i have a huge number of file where converting them manually is impossible . is there any way to convert file inside iOS app code ?

Answer (score 0):

To address your comment about converting the files manually: Is it a plausible solution for you to do it automatically, server side? If so, you probably have a few options.

One would be to install Audacity, which handles all of these bit rates, and use the Chains feature for batch processing. If it's a one-off conversion you could initiate it manually, otherwise you may need to find a way of scripting the process (if new files come in from an external source, that is).

As for playing these files in iOS, have you considered embedding libpd (just one example of many, but one that you can get up and running in minutes)? It has a fairly open approach to file playback, and may handle these file formats. If you send me an example I can test right away!